# Помогите определить, где сказуемое

Tags: сказуемые

Что-то я совсем уже.. "**Он не достоин служить**" - где тут сказуемое? Это составное именное "достоин служить"? Или чем тут *достоин* и *служить* являются?

Answer (score 1):

*Он не достоин служить*.   Лексическое значение в инфинитиве, достоин - краткое прилагательное, обозначающее невозможность действия служить, выполняет роль вспомогательного глагола. Следовательно, это составное глагольное сказуемое, по смыслу равное "*Он не может служить*"